# Undefined value when assigning value in interface

Tags: angular

I am getting an undefined value when using an interface and setting a value

Interface

```
export interface CalculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest {
  accountNumber: string,
  advanceAmount: string
}
```

TS

```
public calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest: CalculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest;
this.accountNumber = '12345';

calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment() {
    this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest.accountNumber = this.accountNumber;
    console.log(this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest.accountNumber);
    this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest.advanceAmount = this.tileData.account.advanceAmount;
  
    this.avafService.CalculateAVAFLoanAdjustment(this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest).subscribe((resp)=>{
     ...
    })
}
```

When I console.log(this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest.accountNumber) I get an undefined value. Any ideas why? Do I perhaps have to do something to the interface before I can use it here?

Comment: Obviously, you are declaring the variable `calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest`. Where are you initializing it's value? It will be undefined until you do that.

Comment: Try `console.log('this.accountNumber',this.accountNumber)` and see if you get undefined

Comment: @dota2pro no I get the value there.

Comment: @R.Richards I am setting the value `this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest.accountNumber = this.accountNumber;`, how would I declare it?

Comment: Where are you setting `this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest`? Declaring a variable does not mean that it is automatically initialized with a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment() {
        this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest = {
         accountNumber: '',
         advanceAmount: ''
        }; // Initialize object
        this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest.accountNumber = this.accountNumber;
        console.log(this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest.accountNumber);
```